# when FlatList inside FlatList or ScrollView , I got a TypeError

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

```js
class TestClass extends PureComponent<Props> {
    private leftFilterFlatListRef = null;
    private rightFilterFlatListRef = null;

    private setLeftFilterFlatListRef = ref => {
        this.leftFilterFlatListRef = ref;
    };
    private setRightFilterFlatListRef = ref => {
        this.rightFilterFlatListRef = ref;
    };
    private onRightFilterGroupItemTitleClickInner = index => {
        this.rightFilterFlatListRef &&
            this.rightFilterFlatListRef.scrollToIndex({
                animated: true,
                index,
                viewPosition: 0
            });
    };
    private onLeftFilterItemClickInner = index => {
        console.log('======context====' + JSON.stringify(this.rightFilterFlatListRef.scrollToIndex)); // undefined
        this.rightFilterFlatListRef &&
            this.rightFilterFlatListRef.scrollToIndex({
                animated: true,
                index,
                viewPosition: 0
            });
    };
    public leftFilterScrollTo = index => {
        this.leftFilterFlatListRef &&
            this.leftFilterFlatListRef.scrollToIndex({
                animated: true,
                index: index,
                viewPosition: 1
            });
    };
    public rightFilterScrollTo = index => {
        this.rightFilterFlatListRef &&
            this.rightFilterFlatListRef.scrollToIndex({
                animated: true,
                index,
                viewPosition: 0
            });
    };

    private renderLeftFilterItem = () => {
        return <LeftItemComponent item={item} index={index} onLeftFilterItemClick={this.onLeftFilterItemClickInner} />;
    };

    private renderRightFilterItem = () => {
        return (
            <RightItemComponent
                index={index}
                item={item}
                onRightFilterGroupItemTitleClick={this.onRightFilterGroupItemTitleClickInner}
            />
        );
    };
    private renderLeftFlatItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        return this.renderLeftFilterItem(this.props, item, index, this.props.onVisible);
    };
    private renderRightFlatItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        return this.renderRightFilterItem(this.props, item, index, this.props.onVisible);
    };

    render(): React.ReactNode {
        const { leftFilterData, rightFilterData } = this.props;
        const nonNullLeftFilterData = leftFilterData || [];
        const nonNullRightFilterData = rightFilterData || [];
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={nonNullLeftFilterData}
                    ref={this.setLeftFilterFlatListRef}
                    renderItem={this.renderLeftFlatItem}
                />
                <FlatList
                    data={nonNullRightFilterData}
                    ref={this.setRightFilterFlatListRef}
                    renderItem={this.renderRightFlatItem}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I got the Error message

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this._scrollRef.scrollTo...')

When I put `TestClass` inside a `FlatList` or `ScrollView`. I found that the `Ref.scrollToIndex` from `FlatList` was undefined. But I want to get the `scrollToIndex` function, and it should be executed rightly.

Comment: The way that you are creating and updating the refs here is bizarre.  I highly recommend that you convert this to a function component and use the `useRef` hook.

Comment: I’m unclear on the issue.  Are you trying to use this TestClass inside another component? And call the  leftFilterScrollTo and rightFilterScrollTo imperatively?  If so, please edit your post to include that component’s code as well.

Comment: yes, I use this TestClass inside another FlatList, and click leftFlatItem, then rightFlatItem scroll to certain item. I am sorry  I couldn't express it clearly. Now I understand this problem.  The  FlatList in TestClass has the same Orientation with outer FlatList where I want to put TestClass inside.  when i do this, FlatList in TestComponent becomes View.  I need add a property called "renderScrollComponent" for each FlatList in TestClass. Then the FlatList in TestClass will be ScrollView not View.  And TestClass works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all .  I understand why  this.rightFilterFlatListRef.scrollToIndex can not be executed rightly. there is some code in VirtualizedList.

```js
  _defaultRenderScrollComponent = props => {
    const onRefresh = props.onRefresh;
    if (this._isNestedWithSameOrientation()) {
      // $FlowFixMe - Typing ReactNativeComponent revealed errors
      return <View {...props} />;
    } else if (onRefresh) {
      invariant(
        typeof props.refreshing === 'boolean',
        '`refreshing` prop must be set as a boolean in order to use `onRefresh`, but got `' +
          /* $FlowFixMe(>=0.111.0 site=react_native_fb) This comment suppresses
           * an error found when Flow v0.111 was deployed. To see the error,
           * delete this comment and run Flow. */
          JSON.stringify(props.refreshing) +
          '`',
      );
      return (
        // $FlowFixMe Invalid prop usage
        <ScrollView
          {...props}
          refreshControl={
            props.refreshControl == null ? (
              <RefreshControl
                refreshing={props.refreshing}
                onRefresh={onRefresh}
                progressViewOffset={props.progressViewOffset}
              />
            ) : (
              props.refreshControl
            )
          }
        />
      );
    } else {
      // $FlowFixMe Invalid prop usage
      return <ScrollView {...props} />;
    }
  };
```

when FlatList A is inside FlatList B, FlatList A becomes View

we add <ScrollView {...props} /> as a prop of FlatList A.  Then FlatList A can scroll again.